# Rx-java 2 : How to set priority between Observables?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an algorithme that is based on time, in some situations two emissions could happen on the same moment from different observables.

See the code below :

```
   int moment = ...; //calculated
   Observable.timer(moment, unit)
    .takeUntil(messages) 
    .map(e -> new Action())
```

The `messages` Observable is executed on `Schedulers.computation()`, like the timer.

When a message comes at the same moment with timer, the behavior is random. Sometimes a new `Action` is emitted, other times not, the `takeUntil(messages)` takes precedence.

I need to have a full control on this behavior. Of course i can add a few milliseconds to `moment`, like so it'll be always executed after `messages`, but this is not what i want.

How to tell RxJava that `messages` observable takes priority over the timer ?

**UPDATE** :

To clarify the question, i added this test, which it success each time it's executed

```
    //before launching the test
    RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler(scheduler ->
                        new TestScheduler());


    @Test
    public void rx_precedence() {

        int moment = 5;
        Observable<Long> messages = Observable.timer(moment, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        TestObserver<Long> testObserver = Observable.timer(moment, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .takeUntil(messages)
                .test();

        scheduler.advanceTimeTo(moment, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        testObserver.assertNoValues();
        testObserver.assertTerminated();
    }
```

Being at the same `moment`, the `takeUntil` is executed and no values are emitted.

But on the server, in the real world, when je JVM is doing multiple things at the same time, the `timer` could takes precedence over the `takeUntil`.

I need a way to make this precedence stable on any environnement, so that no values will be emitted when `messages` emits a value at the same time the `timer` runs out.

Comment: Just to understand the issue. You want to make sure the action is executed if the timer runs out, unless `messages` emits or completes, at which point you do nothing?

Comment: @Fred, i updated the question with a test, do you think it's clear now ?

Comment: Why you are not trying only to observe the action and observable will call when the message comming?

Comment: If you are dependent on the time, you can observe the message and calculating time. When the observable calls and message receive you can return the spent time

Comment: From the test it seems the problem could be solved by changing the schedulers. Why not use the variant of `timer` that receives a scheduler?  Set them to `trampoline` and see if it works. I'm not sure if this is a proper solution, but it might help.

Comment: @Amir could you put some code please ? I cannot follow you !

Comment: @Fred I tried to change the scheduler but the result is more unwanted. I think this couldn't be controlled, it's totally async !

Answer (score 0):

You neeed `Observable.amb()` I suppose -
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/amb.html

UPDATE:
Ok the issue is more clear now. Perhaps `Scheduler.single()` will help.

Comment: The problem is randomness. Amb Won’t help me. Tks

Comment: Then `.sample()` perhaps?

Comment: Sorry i don't get you, the code is shown in the question, i want to fix it. Can you post you solution with `.sample()` to do the same thing above ?